# Raven Index creation gets compilation error CS1977 when using FindLastIndex

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to write an index that looks at our logs to find entities that are unavailable due to undergoing a part of the process but not a second part of the process which then makes them available. Our import process happens first, then our clean process. Entities that have gone through our clean process are then considered available. I want to essentially find out those entities that have undergone the import process (therefore resetting them) after the last time the cleaning occurred.

I came up with this potential map:

```
AddMap<EntityLog>(docs => docs.Where(doc => doc.Details != null)
        .Where(doc => doc.Details.Any(d => d.QueueMessage != null && d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Import)
            && d.Finished != null))
        .Where(doc => doc.Details.Any(d => d.QueueMessage != null && d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Clean)
            && d.Finished != null))
        .Where(doc => doc.Details.FindLastIndex(d => d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Clean) && d.Finished != null) <
            doc.Details.FindLastIndex(d => d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Import) && d.Finished != null))
        .Select(found => new
        {
            found.EntityID,
            User = found.Details.Select(d => d.User)
       }));
```

It compiles in VS, but when I try to make this index, I get the following error:

CS1977 "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

From some selective commenting, it seems to be the line where I'm using FindLastIndex. And from research, I know that this compiler error comes in when you're trying to do stuff with untyped objects that you're not supposed to. From looking at the output Raven-made code, it uses dynamic a lot, so I'm guessing its something related to that. I did try using this as an alternative to that line:

```
.Where(doc => Array.FindLastIndex(doc.Details.ToArray(), d => d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Clean) && d.Finished != null) <
            Array.FindLastIndex(doc.Details.ToArray(), d => d.QueueMessage.JobsToDo.Contains(JobType.Import) && d.Finished != null))
```

But no joy, I still get the same error message.

How do I get this code to work? Or do I need to take a completely different approach?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a create a get only property on your `EntityLog` that uses the `FindLastIndex` then the results of that information is what will be serialized to the database and easy to search upon.

This is a rather common pattern I follow when working with Lists.

```
public class Foo {
    public List<Phones> Phones { get;set; }

    public Phone PrimaryPhone { 
            get { return Phones.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Primary == true)) }
    }    
}
```

Note, if `EntityLog` is an already existing document collection, you will need to Load each log and save it back to the database.

Comment: Since whenever we update the logs we load them anyway and store them back rather than patching or anything, this would work for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FindLastIndex is a method on List, but we don't know what the type is on the server side, so that isn't available.
Use the extension method on IEnumerable, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried casting it to ((IEnumerable)doc.Details) but I don't get anything useful here. Am I missing something?